# Attaching a tree to a grid

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

The program I'm writing doesn't display the tree. The program outputs the following error:

> (gtk:3210): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_grid_attach_next_to: assertion 'gtk_widget_get_parent (child) == NULL' failed

The code obviously fails at that function, and I have no clue why. The tree I set up is the same as the sample code. The only difference is the grid, but I thought I could attach a tree like any other widget. Does anyone know how to attach it properly, or did I miss something?

```
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Main window
    GtkWidget*          window;
    GtkWidget*          grid;
    GtkWidget*          box;

    // Menubar
    GtkWidget*          menubar;
    GtkWidget*          filemenu;
    GtkWidget*          file;
    GtkWidget*          quit;

    // List
    GtkWidget*          tree;
    GtkTreeStore*       store;
    GtkTreeIter         iter;
    GtkCellRenderer*    renderer;
    GtkTreeViewColumn*  column;

    /*
     * Setup the window and the main grid.
     */
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "imgedit");
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 600, 400);

    grid = gtk_grid_new ();

    /*
     * Create the menubar, and all of it's menus.
     */
    box = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
    menubar = gtk_menu_bar_new ();
    filemenu = gtk_menu_new ();
    file = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label ("File");
    quit = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label ("Quit");

    gtk_menu_item_set_submenu (GTK_MENU_ITEM (file), filemenu);
    gtk_menu_shell_append (GTK_MENU_SHELL (filemenu), quit);
    gtk_menu_shell_append (GTK_MENU_SHELL (menubar), file);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (box), menubar, FALSE, FALSE, 3);

    /*
     * Setup the list with files.
     */
    store = gtk_tree_store_new (3, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_UINT, G_TYPE_UINT);
    gtk_tree_store_append (store, &iter, NULL);
    gtk_tree_store_set (store, &iter, FILE_NAME, "test name", FILE_OFFSET, 0, FILE_SIZE, 10, -1);

    tree = gtk_tree_view_new_with_model (GTK_TREE_MODEL (store));
    g_object_unref (G_OBJECT (store));
    renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new ();

    column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes ("Name", renderer, "text", FILE_NAME, NULL);
    gtk_tree_view_append_column (GTK_TREE_VIEW (tree), column);

    /*
     * Attach the grid to the main window and connect all signals.
     */
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), GTK_WIDGET (grid));
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), box, 1, 1, 1, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach_next_to (GTK_GRID (grid), box, tree, GTK_POS_BOTTOM, 1, 1);

    g_signal_connect (quit, "activate", G_CALLBACK (event_quit), GTK_WINDOW (window));
    g_signal_connect (window, "delete-event", G_CALLBACK (event_delete), GTK_WINDOW (window));
    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all (window);

    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the order of arguments to `gtk_grid_attach_next_to()`. You are telling it to attach `box` next to `tree` instead of vice versa, but `tree` is not yet attached and `box` was already attached in the previous line.

Although the error message may seem cryptic at first sight, you really can get all the information you need from it: for starters, "assertion failed" should be your first clue, that the input to a function is invalid. (Many GTK functions start out by asserting that their inputs are valid.)

The next clue is to look at what the assertion was that failed: `gtk_widget_get_parent (child) == NULL`. In other words this is "the parent widget of `child` is `NULL`" or in plain English "the `child` widget doesn't have a parent (and is therefore not yet inside a container.)" That assertion *failed*, so the opposite must be true.

Look at the call to `gtk_grid_attach_next_to()`, and note that you have passed `box` as the `child` parameter; so the assertion is telling you, "`box` is not supposed to be already inside a container, but it is inside one anyway." And indeed, you put it in a container on the previous line using `gtk_grid_attach()`.